# Por favor alguém me explica essa sintaxe: Estou confundindo o símbolo -> com o símbolo =>

Tags: php

```
$produto = array();
$produto['descricao'] = 'Chocolate Amargo';
$produto['estoque'] = 150;
$produto['preco'] = 2;

$objeto = new stdClass;
foreach($produto as $chave=>$valor){
    $objeto->$chave = $valor;
}

echo $objeto->descricao;
```

Comment: `=>` é usado somente para acesso em dados do tipo array, `->` é usado para acesso a propriedades em um objeto

Comment: lembrando que para converter o array `$produto` em objeto, basta fazer assim: `$objeto=(object)$produto;`

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento gente.

Answer (score 4):

Basicamente você usa o `->` para acessar propriedades de objetos (objetos definidos por você ou até mesmo um stdClass) e o `=>` para endereçar um conteúdo em algum lugar.

Vejamos alguns exemplos:

```php
<?php

class Foo {
    // Criamos um atributo $name para o objeto Foo.
    public $name = 'Bar';
}

// Instânciamos o objeto.
$foo = new Foo;

// Acessamos sua propriedade utilizando o ->
echo $foo->name;
```

Agora, vamos para alguns usos do `=>` (que como falei, serve para endereçar um conteúdo em algum lugar).

```php
// Colocamos o conteúdo Bar dentro do índice name do array $foo.
$foo = array(
    'name' => 'Bar'
);

foreach( $bars as $key=>$values ) {
     // Ou seja, temos um array de $bars e percorremos cada um.
     // O $values é alterado a cada iteração desse foreach.
     // O $key é o índice de cada iteração (0, 1, 2 e etc).
}
```

Comment: Ah sim agora entendi, muito obrigado Luciano.